# asp.net mvc 4 web api forms authentication tutorial

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I am new to asp.net mvc 4 web api and setting up a single page application which will be hosted on the intranet internally in the companies firewall. The users of this app will need to use their windows network login to access it.

I need to create a my own login page and can't use the default IIS login screen which comes with asp.net windows authentication.

Is there any nice and easy tutorial for beginners that I can read before setting up this project.

Also, in the front end we will be using angularjs